# Dialogflow Messenger Custom Payload Quick Respose Issue - Clicked input not understood/matched in Dialogflow ES

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to add quick responses to allow users to click rather than type into Dialogflow Messenger I have used:

```
    {
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "event": {
          "parameters": {},
          "languageCode": "en",
          "name": "yes"
        },
        "type": "button",
        "text": "Yes",
        "link": "",
        "icon": {
          "type": "chevron_right",
          "color": "#FF9800"
        }
      },
      {
        "link": "",
        "type": "button",
        "event": {
          "parameters": {},
          "name": "no",
          "languageCode": "en"
        },
        "text": "No",
        "icon": {
          "type": "chevron_right",
          "color": "#FF9800"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This generates the clickable links all OK however when you actually click 'yes' or 'no' in messenger, Dialogueflow doesn't understand the input see screenshot 1:
[image: Screen shot of response]

Whereas typing in 'yes' or 'no' works as expected see screenshot 2:
[image: works when keyed in text]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi, If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also tested the rich response messages using list and button response types on Dialogflow Messenger using custom payload, and I'm also facing the same problem. If I click the button/list, it triggers a default fallback intent response. So, It seems only possible with webhook calls that manage the event and retrieve text.

I was unable to find any direct demonstration of how to call a webhook for an event triggered on a button click and then return a text response. Already, a feature request was raised similar to your issue on the Google Cloud [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171904225). You can follow the updates from there.

[image]

For your requirement, you can try using the [suggestion chip response type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#suggestion_chip_response_type) with the following custom payload and test it:

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "chips",
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "Yes"
          },
          {
            "text": "No"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Result:

[image]

Once you click the Yes/No suggestion chip, you can see the selected chip as input and response for it in the below image.

[image]

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Perfect, yes, 'chips' work whilst buttons etc do not, thanks for helping